# What should be best Nginx Cache on top of Nginx Server or Varnish cache on top of Nginx server for small VPS?

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-reverse-proxy, varnish, ubuntu-20.04

I am thinking to install varnish cache on a small VPS configuration. My VPS configuration is 2 core CPU & 2 GB RAM with 50 GB SSD.

I would like to know on such small VPS configuration what should be best to install

1. Varnish Cache, Nginx Web server (PHP & MySQL also)
2. Nginx Cache (for static file caching) on top of Nginx webserver along with PHP & MySQL

Fyi I also need to install SSL on all virtual host. What I know by default Varnish doesn't work on SSL. There should be additional things has to be installed to support SSL. So if I have to install multiple service on server to support varnish cache does it not better to use the nginx only with nginx cache remembering the server specs are low.

I am waiting for an open discussion to find best solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your production Queries per Second are less than 5 after your busiest hour of uptime, keep your life simple and only install required MySQL, PHP and SSL support.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is a great webserver, but isn't a specialized reverse caching proxy. Varnish is specifically built for caching and its caching policies are far more granular.

### Components

- Use Hitch as your TLS proxy
- Use Varnish for caching
- Use Nginx as your webserver and connect to Nginx from Varnish

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/ for a tutorial on how to install Hitch for TLS termination.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/#installations for a list of tutorials (per platform and distribution) on how to install Varnish.

### Port configuration

- Configure Nginx to listen on port `8080`
- Configure Varnish to listen on port `80`
- Add an additional listening interface in Varnish on port `8443` for PROXY protocol traffic
- Configure Hitch to listen on port `443`
- Let Hitch connect to Varnish over port `8443` via the PROXY protocol
- Let Varnish connect to Nginx over port `8080` via a `backend` definition

Answer (score 0):

varnish cache community edition doesn't support TLS connection to the backends.